# Best way to access tree structure c++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, containers

I need to implement a generic Tree structure with variable number of nodes. I'd like to address nodes via a key relative to the structure and not the memory.
The expected use is :

```
...
Tree<int> t ;
auto r = t.set_root(4) ; // set 4 as root, r is a key to acces the created node
auto a = t.append(r,5,2) ; // append 5 as 2nd child of r, a is the key of the created node

Tree<int> v = t ;
v.append(a,4,1) // set 4 as 1st child of node indexed by a in v, t is not modified
...
```

I started with the following structure to implement this :

```
template< typename T >
struct Node {

    Node(T dat):mData(dat),mChilds(0,std::shared_ptr<Node<T>>()) {}

    Node(Node const& n):mData(n.mData),mChilds(n.mChilds.size(),std::shared_ptr<Node<T>>()) {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < mChilds.size() ; i++ ) {
            if( n.mChilds[i] ) {
                mChilds[i].reset(new Node<T>(*(n.mChilds[i]))) ;
            }
        }
    }

    ~Node() { }

    T mData ;
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> > mChilds ;

    Node<T>& operator=(Node<T> t) {
        std::swap(t.mData,this->mData);
        std::swap(t.mChilds,this->mChilds);
        return *this ;
    }
};

template< typename T >
struct Tree {

    Tree ():mRoot() {}

    Tree ( Tree<T> const& t) :mRoot() {
        mRoot.reset(new Node_t(*(t.mRoot)));
    }
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> mRoot ;

    Tree<T>& operator=(Tree<T> t) {
        std::swap(t.mRoot,this->mRoot);
        return *this ;
    }
};
```

I actually use :

```
 typedef std::vector<int> key_t ;
```

as my key to access nodes, I store the path to follow to reach my data. This works well but I'm worried about the size in memory that could take the key if a node is deep.

Has anyone a better idea for this key ? Or for the whole structure but as I need to cut siblings, swap them between trees etc. I think that the linked structure is the best...

I know there are libs lihe Tree.hh or the BGL that would fit but I can not use external libs

Thx for replies

Comment: In "append 5 as 2nd child of r" what happens if there is not exactly 1 child already?

Comment: Also I'm not sure why `shared_ptr` is being used; if you have a node in a tree included by two different parents then things will go to crap very fast, and it seems that you don't intend for different trees to share their elements ?

Comment: Your `key_t` sounds like it is required, otherwise there is no way for `v` to know where in its tree corresponds to `a`.  And that could malfunction if the tree is modified after the copy but before the use of `a`.

Comment: @Matt McNabb 1. If there is less than 1 the vector is resized else the pointing node is detroyed and replaced. 2. No, different trees will not share element, this is not a feature I need and I was using pointers before using smart pointers. 3. That was my conclusion also, I was hoping to reduce the memory size of the key_t but if it is not possible, I will keep my vector